# C++ sieve of Eratosthenes with array

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'd like to code the famous Sieve of Eratosthenes in C++ using just array as it would be a set where I can delete some elements on the way to find out primes numbers.
I don't want to use STL (vector, set)... Just array! How can I realize it?

I try to explain why I don't want to use STL set operator: I'm learning C++ from the very beginning and I think STL is of course useful for programmers but built on standard library, so I'd like to use former operators and commands. I know that everything could be easier with STL.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Good idea? Not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to [the sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)'s efficiency is that it does not, repeat ***not***, delete ⁄ remove ⁄ throw away ⁄ etc. the composites as it enumerates them, but instead just *marks* them as such.

Keeping all the numbers preserves our ability to use a number's value as its address in this array and thus directly address it: `array[n]`. This is what makes the sieve's enumeration and marking off of each prime's multiples efficient, when implemented on modern [random-access memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) computers (just as with the [integer sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting)).

To make that array simulate a set, we give each entry two possible values, flags: `on` and `off`, `prime` or `composite`, `1` or `0`. Yes, we actually only need one *bit*, not byte, to represent each number in the sieve array, *provided* we do not remove any of them while working on it.

And btw, `vector<bool>` is automatically packed, representing `bool`s by bits. Very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

From [Algorithms and Data Structures](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {

      int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int)sqrt((double)upperBound);
      bool *isComposite = new bool[upperBound + 1];
      memset(isComposite, 0, sizeof(bool) * (upperBound + 1));

      for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {  
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                  cout << m << " ";
                  for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m)
                        isComposite[k] = true;
            }
      }
      for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++)
            if (!isComposite[m])
                  cout << m << " ";

      delete [] isComposite;
}


int main()
{
 runEratosthenesSieve(1000);
}
```

You don't want to use STL, but that's not a good idea

STL makes life much simpler.

Still consider this implementation using `std::map`

```
int  max = 100;
S sieve;

for(int it=2;it < max;++it)
    sieve.insert(it);

for(S::iterator it = sieve.begin();it != sieve.end();++it)
{
    int  prime   = *it;
    S::iterator x = it;
    ++x;
    while(x != sieve.end())
        if (((*x) % prime) == 0)
            sieve.erase(x++);
        else
            ++x;
}

for(S::iterator it = sieve.begin();it != sieve.end();++it)
 std::cout<<*it<<std::endl;
```